# How do place a field value from a map into a list

Tags: apex, list, map, id

I have a map from which I want to place the Id's of a field into a List. I tried the following:

```
Map<String, Relatie__c> uniqueHuish = new map<String, Relatie__c>(); 
    for(Relatie__c rc: rcList) {
        if(!uniqueHuish.containsKey(rc.Huishouden__c)) {
            uniqueHuish.put(rc.Huishouden__c,rc);
        }
    }
    Relatie__c[] uniqueHuishList = uniqueHuish.values();
```

If I debug uniqueHuishList I get:

```
DEBUG|uniqueHuishList (Relatie__c:{Contactpersoon__c=0014E00000PD14ABCD, Account__c=0032E00000Vag7ABCD, Huishouden__c=a133E000000HyABCD, Relatietype__c=Lid, Id=a009E000002YaCABCD})
```

What I want to end up with is a List of only the IDs of Huishouden__c. How do I extract the Huishouden__c into a list? If i try keyset() I get the error Illegal assignment from set to list.

Comment: are you looking some thing like this:map<id,list<id>>uniqueHuish=new map<id,list<id>>();
for(Relatie__c rc: rcList) {
        if(!uniqueHuish.containsKey(rc.Huishouden__c)) {
uniqueHuish.put(rc.id,new List<id>());
        }
else{
uniqueHuish.get(rc.id).add(rc.Huishouden__c);
}if you put system.debug(':::'+uniqueHuish.values()); //List of ids of Huishouden__c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a Set to populate the list of field values from your SObject list.

```
Set<String> uniqueHuish = new Set<String>(); 
for(Relatie__c rc: rcList) {
        uniqueHuish.add(rc.Huishouden__c);
    }
}
```

of if you want to continue using the map if its being used for some other purpose, then you can retrieve the set of Ids (Keys) alone using

```
uniqueHuish.keySet()
```

Comment: @vamshi krishna your code: "Relatie__c"  --> Set<String,Relatie__c> uniqueHuish = new Set<String, Relatie__c>();

Comment: thx @AnnappaPH. updated.

Comment: welcome @Vamshi Krishna  :)

Comment: @VamsiKrishna Can I use ID instead of string in this case?

Comment: yes @Thomas you can use Set<Id> ..

Answer (score 1):

You can add all elements of set to a list of same type.

```
Map<String, Relatie__c> uniqueHuish = new Map<String, Relatie__c>(); 
for(Relatie__c rc: rcList) {
    if(!uniqueHuish.containsKey(rc.Huishouden__c)) {
        uniqueHuish.put(rc.Huishouden__c, rc);
    }
}
List<ID> uniqueHuishList = new List<ID>();
uniqueHuishList.addAll(uniqueHuish.keySet());
system.debug(':::'+uniqueHuishList);
```

Comment: I get an  incorrect signature: void addAll(Set<String>) from the type List<Id>?

Comment: Typo. List uniqueHuishList must be declared as List<String>

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for map try this code,or using set or list set you can easily collect the ids.

```
 map<id,list<id>>uniqueHuish=new map<id,list<id>>(); 
  for(Relatie__c rc: rcList) { 
  if(!uniqueHuish.containsKey(rc.Huishouden__c)) { 
   uniqueHuish.put(rc.id,new List<id>()); 
  } 
   else
    { 
    uniqueHuish.get(rc.id).add(rc.Huishouden__c); 
 }
system.debug(':::'+uniqueHuish.values());
```